# Нужно сделать голосование по реакциям и вывод победителя (discord python)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Есть сообщение, которое отправляет бот. На сообщение добавляется 4 реакции. После 10 секунд голосования выводится сообщение с победителем.

```
    embed = discord.Embed(title ="Выбор карты для игры", description = "Вот список карт, которые можно выбрать:\n1.Sandstone\n2.⛲️Province\n3.Rust\n4.☢️zone 9", colour = discord.Colour.from_rgb(0, 204, 102))
    check = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await check.add_reaction('\U0001F3DC')
    await check.add_reaction('\U000026F2')
    await check.add_reaction('\U0001F5FF')
    await check.add_reaction('\U00002622')
    time.sleep(10)
    embed = discord.Embed(title =f"Голосование #{game} окончено!", description ='Играем карту, на которой больше реакций.', colour = discord.Colour.from_rgb(0, 204, 102))
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Не знаю как сделать подсчёт реакций и сравнение их с выводом.

UPD: Дополнил код, в консоль ничего не выводится.

```
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
from asyncio import sleep

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '=') 
TOKEN = #тут мой токен

@bot.command(pass_context =True)
async def test(ctx):
  embed = discord.Embed(title ="Выбор карты для игры", description = "Вот список карт, которые можно выбрать:\n1.Sandstone\n2.⛲️Province\n3.Rust\n4.☢️zone 9", colour = discord.Colour.from_rgb(0, 204, 102))
  msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed) #текст с голосованием
  await msg.add_reaction('\U0001F3DC')
  await msg.add_reaction('\U000026F2')
  await msg.add_reaction('\U0001F5FF')
  await msg.add_reaction('\U00002622')#добавляем реакции для голосования
  await sleep(10)#даем время на голосование
  for reaction in msg.reactions:
    print(reaction, reaction.count)#Этот код мне дали в ответах и он ничего не выводит
  embed = discord.Embed(title =f"Голосование окончено!", description ='Играем карту, на которой больше реакций.', colour = discord.Colour.from_rgb(0, 204, 102))
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)#тут нужно сделать подсчёт количество нажатых реакций на каждой реакции. Далее сравниваем и выводим победителя
bot.run(TOKEN)
‘’’
```

Answer (score 0):

Получить список реакций сообщения можно из атрибута `reactions`.

Получить количество поставленных реакций, можно из полученной до этого реакции, из атрибута `count`.

Затем, по прошествии времени, мы можем в цикле для списка **реакций**, выводить саму реакцию, а также ее **количество**

**Перезапишем сообщение:**

```
msg = await msg.channel.fetch_message(msg.id)
```

**Считаем реакции:**

```
for reaction in check.reactions:
    print(reaction, reaction.count)
```

**Затем, имея доступ к количеству каждой реакции, думаю, вы разберетесь, как их сравнить и вывести наибольшую.**

---

**Пример:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Результат:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Полный код:**

```
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
from asyncio import sleep
import discord

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '=') 

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title ="Выбор карты для игры", description = "Вот список карт, которые можно выбрать:\n1.Sandstone\n2.⛲️Province\n3.Rust\n4.☢️zone 9", colour = discord.Colour.from_rgb(0, 204, 102))
    msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed) #текст с голосованием
    await msg.add_reaction('\U0001F3DC')
    await msg.add_reaction('\U000026F2')
    await msg.add_reaction('\U0001F5FF')
    await msg.add_reaction('\U00002622')#добавляем реакции для голосования
    await sleep(10)#даем время на голосование

    msg = await msg.channel.fetch_message(msg.id)

    for reaction in msg.reactions:
        print(reaction, reaction.count)#Этот код мне дали в ответах и он ничего не выводит

    embed = discord.Embed(title =f"Голосование окончено!", description ='Играем карту, на которой больше реакций.', colour = discord.Colour.from_rgb(0, 204, 102))
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)#тут нужно сделать подсчёт количество нажатых реакций на каждой реакции. Далее сравниваем и выводим победителя

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: `for reaction in msg.reactions:
    print(reaction, reaction.count)#этот код ничего не выводит`

Comment: Прошу прощения, ошибся, нужно вместо msg подставить check

Comment: Код все ровно ничего не выдаёт, а с msg на check я и так поменял.

Comment: Дополните текст вашего вопроса кодом

Comment: Дополнил текст вопроса полным кодом

Comment: Вам в цикле нужно check обратно на msg поменять) `for reaction in msg.reactions`

Comment: Ну увидел, когда дополнял вопрос, все ровно код ничего не выдаёт.

Comment: Странно. Можно попробовать по прошествии 10 секунд заново записывать в переменную объект сообщения. Дополнил ответ

Comment: Этот код сработал, но если выводить `print(reaction.count)`,  то выводятся количестово нажатых каждые на новой строке.Как мне их записать в переменные для каждой реакции-количество нажатий? Например `reaction1= #тут число нажатий 1 реакции` и т.д.

Comment: Вам не нужно записывать их в отдельные переменные. У вас уже все записано в массиве `msg.reactions`. Чтобы получить количество 1 реакции, обращайтесь к `msg.reactions[0].count`, второй - `msg.reactions[1].count` и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо, код работает!